# How do you write data structures that are as efficient as possible in GHC?

Tags: data-structures, haskell

So sometimes I need to write a data structure I can't find on Hackage, or what I find isn't tested or quality enough for me to trust, or it's just something I don't want to be a dependency. I am reading Okasaki's book right now, and it's quite good at explaining how to design asymptotically fast data structures.

However, I am working specifically with GHC. Constant factors are a big deal for my applications. Memory usage is also a big deal for me. So I have questions specifically about GHC.

In particular

- How to maximize sharing of nodes
- How to reduce memory footprint
- How to avoid space leaks due to improper strictness/laziness
- How to get GHC to produce tight inner loops for important sections of code

I've looked around various places on the web, and I have a *vague* idea of how to work with GHC, for example, looking at core output, using `UNPACK` pragmas, and the like. But I'm not sure I get it.

So I popped open my favorite data structures library, containers, and looked at the Data.Sequence module. I can't say I understand a lot of what they're doing to make Seq fast.

The first thing that catches my eye is the definition of `FingerTree a`. I assume that's just me being unfamiliar with finger trees though. The second thing that catches my eye is all the `SPECIALIZE` pragmas. I have no idea what's going on here, and I'm very curious, as these are littered all over the code.

Many functions also have an `INLINE` pragma associated with them. I can guess what that means, but how do I make a judgement call on when to `INLINE` functions?

Things get really interesting around line ~475, a section headered as 'Applicative Construction'. They define a newtype wrapper to represent the Identity monad, they write their own copy of the strict state monad, and they have a function defined called `applicativeTree` which, apparently is specialized to the Identity monad and this increases sharing of the output of the function. I have no idea what's going on here. What sorcery is being used to increase sharing?

Anyway, I'm not sure there's much to learn from Data.Sequence. Are there other 'model programs' I can read to gain wisdom? I'd really like to know how to soup up my data structures when I really need them to go faster. One thing in particular is writing data structures that make fusion easy, and how to go about writing good fusion rules.

Comment: If memory serves me, the canonical answer to this question is "get your problem added to [the language benchmarks game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/) and wait for Don to optimize it for you". ;]

Comment: hahaha. Maybe I should eat Dons, thus gaining his uncanny power to create Haskell code that competes with C.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's a big topic! Most has been explained elsewhere, so I won't  try to write a book chapter right here. Instead:

- Real World Haskell, ch 25, "[Performance](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html)" - discusses profiling, simple specialization and unpacking, reading Core, and some optimizations.

Johan Tibell is writing a lot on this topic:

- [Computing the size of a data structure](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/computing-size-of-hashmap.html)
- [Memory footprints of common data types](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html)
- [Faster persistent structures through hashing](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/03/video-of-my-hashing-based-containers.html)
- [Reasoning about laziness](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/02/slides-from-my-talk-on-reasoning-about.html)

And some things from here:

- [Reading GHC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core/6121495#6121495)
- [How GHC does optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048194/good-introductory-text-about-ghc-implementation/6048706#6048706)
- [Profiling for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276240/tools-for-analyzing-performance-of-a-haskell-program/3276557#3276557)
- [Tweaking GC settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626884/improving-treap-implementation/5690580#5690580)
- [General improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707250/optimizing-numerical-array-performance-in-haskell/5707388#5707388)
- [More on unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115540/haskell-math-performance-on-multiply-add-operation/3134481#3134481)
- [Unboxing and strictness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131554/what-is-the-relationship-between-unboxed-types-and-strictness/3134654#3134654)

And some other things:

- [Intro to specialization of code and data](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/self-optimizing-data-structures-using-types-to-make-lists-faster/)
- [Code improvement flags](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-optimise.html#id455084)

Comment: So is the specialize pragma analogous to your optimizations for data structures, but done automatically and for functions?

Comment: Yeah. Though it is somewhat unnecessary given the presence of INLINE

Comment: SPECIALIZE leads to less code bloat than INLINE as there's only one extra function body per type, rather than one extra function body per call site. My rule of thumb: Use INLINE on functions with higher-order arguments (to avoid an indirect call) and SPECIALIZE otherwise. With the addition of INLINABLE I use that almost exclusive where I would before have used SPECIALIZE, as INLINABLE allows for specialization in a different module.

Comment: My "High-Performance Haskell" talk at CUFP contains a superset of the slides from "Reasoning about laziness". You can find it here: http://blog.johantibell.com/2010/09/slides-from-my-high-performance-haskell.html

Comment: Edward Zhang had an [interesting post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/06/a-pattern-for-increasing-sharing/) on mapping over trees in such a way that you get maximal sharing when the function results would be identical.

Answer (score 13):

[`applicativeTree`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12-latest/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/src/Data-Sequence.html#applicativeTree) is quite fancy, but mainly in a way which has to do with FingerTrees in particular, which are quite a fancy data structure themselves. We had some discussion of the intricacies [over at cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5356). Note that `applicativeTree` is written to work over *any* Applicative. It just so happens that when it is specialized to `Id` then it can share nodes in a manner that it otherwise couldn't. You can work through the specialization yourself by inlining the `Id` methods and seeing what happens. Note that this specialization is used in only one place -- the O(log n) `replicate` function. The fact that the more general function specializes neatly to the constant case is a very clever bit of code reuse, but that's really all.

In general, `Sequence` teaches more about designing persistent data structures than about all the tricks for eeking out performance, I think. Dons' suggestions are of course excellent. I'd also just browse through the source of the *really* canonical and tuned libs -- `Map`, `IntMap`, `Set`, and `IntSet` in particular. Along with those, its worth taking a look at Milan's [paper on his improvements to containers](http://fox.ucw.cz/papers/containers/containers.pdf).

Comment: And HashMap and HashSet, my new favorites.

Comment: @augustss: I agree, except when you browse the source, HashMap and HashSet are, as Milan's paper documents, pretty much thin (but excellent) wrappers around Maps and Sets.

Comment: Have you seen Johan's hashmap? http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/0.1.3.0/doc/html/src/Data-HashMap-Common.html#HashMap

Comment: @Don -- oh, of course. Brain slip on my part there.

Comment: I wrote the `applicativeTree` implementation, back in the day -- and sclv is right that it's mostly there because it's clever.  =P  Yes, it does neatly generalize to make the replicate function O(log n), but it's not a trick that would work for most data structures.